# C# Immutable HashSet locking

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

suppose a server storing an ImmutableHashSet of connection data

```
ImmutableHashSet<ConnectionData> connections = new ...
```

I then have various calls adding/removing/reading from this, ie:

```
OnConnected(connectionData) => connections = connections.Add(connectionData);
OnDisconnected(connectionData) => connections = connections.Remove(connectionData);
```

My question is, in the above calls which only do a single operation on the HashSet (Add/Remove), should I lock connections ? or are ImmutableHashSet operations thread safe?

Comment: You do two operations on `connections` variable.

Comment: *are ImmutableHashSet operations thread safe ?* read the docs - but it is not the whole story

Comment: You should read @EricLippert 's blog series on Immutability from late 2007  it starts here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/. If the collection is immutable, the one you are referencing has internal integrity at all times, and, _it will never change_. But, it's not necessarily the same one that an actor on another thread is referencing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your pattern of assigning the value directly back onto the collection is *not* thread-safe. However, you generally do not want to `lock` when using an immutable collection. One of the major features of these collections are lock-free manipulation, which is often significantly more performant. Instead, use the `ImmutableInterlocked` class:

```
ImmutableHashSet<ConnectionData> connections;

ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref connections,
                            (collection, item) => collection.Add(item),
                            connectionData);

ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref connections,
                            (collection, item) => collection.Remove(item),
                            connectionData);
```

Comment: "you generally do not want to lock when using an immutable collection" - why ?

Comment: @kofifus Lock-free is cheaper because it will on average do a lot less work when there is low contention. During high contention, lock-free will still be faster, but less so -- and it will tend to allocate more. Luckily these allocations will all be in gen-0 GC, which is extremely cheap. That said, if you have high contention then immutable collections are not a good fit regardless of locking: they are not designed for high write contention. You'd want to use something like `ConcurrentDictionary` in that case, which supports actual concurrent use.

Comment: interesting and thanks for the explanations .. is there any good explanation/discussion somewhere of how ImmutableInterlocked works ? (it seems the microsoft docs are just 1-2 lines for each methods)

Comment: @kofifus You can verify what the method does yourself by downloading dotPeek and decompiling `ImmutableInterlocked.Update`. In summary, it calls `Interlocked.CompareExchange` in a loop until it succeeds.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly the returned bool from the Update will in this case represent the result of the hashset method, as in if true is returned the value was added/removed, and if it returns false it means no difference was found between the "old" and new collection (e.g. another thread added/removed before we had a chance to, or the value already existed / never existed)... so... for intents and purposes exactly what you would expect from an Add/Remove method on a HashSet that used locks, yes?

Answer (score 1):

The `Add` and `Remove` method calls return a completely new `ImmutableHashSet`. So, while the type is [thread-safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467171(v=vs.111).aspx#Thread%20Safety), you will need to use locking - to handle scenarios where multiple calls to `Add` or `Remove` occur at the same time. *Otherwise if two `Add` calls occur simultaneously (as an example) you have a classic race condition.*

As such, you will want to use a lock object:

```
private object lockObject = new lockObject();
```

and then use `lock(lockObject)` around each code block that assigns to `connections` (e.g. your `Add` and `Remove` calls).

*See also the great link provided by @Flydog57 in the above comments.*